# How to get CPU usage & Memory consumed by particular service in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I want to find performance of single process, as example "MSSQLSERVER"

Which commands I should write to find out 2 things:

1. RAM utilized by MSSQLSERVER
2. CPU utilized by MSSQLSERVER

I have found command to get service, but not able to get CPU & RAM usage.

Comment: Get-Process and Measure-Object are your friends.

Comment: How about using Performance Monitor to look at Sql Server?

Comment: Thanks for advise mate, I know that way, actually I want to get performance of another service, SQLServer is taken as example here (mentioned in question) I want to achieve this using power shell only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-Process -Name sqlservr | Select-Object ProcessName, CPU, PM
```

Answer (score 0):

as @vonPryz has suggested you may be interrested to use the performance counters.
Here is a starting point :

1. find all the counterset related to sql
   `Get-Counter -ListSet "*"  | ?{ $_.countersetname -match "sql"} | select -Unique countersetname`
2. pick a set from the list above and run get-counter 
   `Get-Counter -ListSet "SQLServer:Workload Group Stats"  |get-counter -SampleInterval 10 -MaxSamples 3}`